# Laravel authentication and authorisation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authorization, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

In my database, there is two table members and services. in that table, there are 5 column
**members**
Username, Rank, Name, Password, and more
**services**
username user_services

I don't want my default login from AUTH controller from ***users*** table but I want login from my ***members*** table and authorize table from another table ***services*** 
if user logins authentication from members table and authorize from services table

Tried everywhere but couldn't get any valuable answer.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change de auth table

Edit ***app/config/auth.php*** to change the table.

```
'table' => 'members',
```

If you need to change field  in ***app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php***

```
public function username()
{
    return 'yourField';
}
```

And you can continuos using AuthController from Laravel

Comment: Inside LoginController , you can use this function , protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)   {   \Session::put('userId', $user->lng );} for example if you want to save userId